# PayPal Security Warning after Payment Completed

Tags: ssl, https, paypal, warnings

I have integrated PayPal in the website. Everything works except when in Firefox, after payment is completed and redirected back to the website, I get a security warning related to my website not having SSL.

How can i make it work without the warning message (without HTTPS cert coz we do not have plan to get it currently)? I used the validation method that the server does not need to have SSL according to the documentation. Is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the alert you're referring to is because you're going from a secure site (HTTPS)to a standard one (HTTP). The only way to avoid it completely is to properly install an SSL certificate.

There are options within a browser that will ignore those alerts but you can't control them for other people.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Patrick. Looks like i have no choice but to ask the client get one SSL cert.